# What's the difference between nohup and ">& nohup.out &"?

Tags: bash, shell, nohup

nohup renders a process immune to the shell's SIGHUP, but even if I run this from my shell:

```
bash -c 'while true; do sleep 1; date; done' >& nohup.out &
```

then log out and log back in, bash is still running and producing output to nohup.out. Is there any difference? Is relying solely on redirection less reliable in any way?

Comment: FYI: in general, these kinds of questions will probably be answered much faster on serverfault.

Comment: @Mikeage: What, just because it's about bash?

Comment: It's fairly Linux specific (and SF tends to have a hgiher percentage of linux users than SU), and this is the kind of things admins do daily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash backgrounded jobs do not need to be protected by *nohup*

Depending on your version of bash, the behaviour can be changed. In the *SIGNALS* section of the manual page

> If the huponexit shell option has been set with shopt, bash sends a SIGHUP to all
>   jobs when an interactive login shell exits.

The *huponexit* option defaults to *off*

Answer (score 1):

`nohup` allows you to [disconnect the execution from the shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup),

> Nohuping backgrounded jobs is typically used to avoid terminating them when logging off from a remote SSH session. A different issue that often arises in this situation is that ssh is refusing to log off ("hangs"), since it refuses to lose any data from/to the background job(s).
>
> This problem can also be overcome by redirecting all three I/O streams:
> `nohup ./myprogram > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &`

Another reference to the [SSH 'hangup' case](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/ssh-hangs-on-exit-when-using-nohup.html).

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, since redirection (*without* nohup) seems to be doing the same thing, as I described.